# google maps dynamic address

Tags: google-maps

I am using a form which allows user to enter his address and submit . 
When user clicks on submit i need to locate his address using Gmap .

How can we achieve this ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the JavaScript API: Geocoding is what you are looking for; http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

Comment: If you look at the example here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingStatusCodes, you can create a Placemark and attach an InfoWindow with it; add the Placemark and show (open ()) the InfoWindow. Refer to the v3 tutorials (or reference) for both.

Comment: Can we locate the map dynamically for address like these:
Ex: RBI, Plot no-55, madhapur, Hyderabad. why because In city "Hyderabad" we can have RBI in different locations . Could you please give me solution on how to locate . thanks